# Python regex replace finding forward slashes with numbers in between

Tags: python, regex

I need to maintain a legacy code which uses regex and the purpose of the code to change a column value (Identification_key) in a csv file which I put 2 lines from

Identification_Key,Identification_Measure

Customer Cube\BFG\0948271//BGF/INTEREST RATE PRODUCTS/,Analytic PFE

Customer Cube\BFG\0957BC/1081991/BGR/,Analytic PFE

first row column value from
Customer Cube\BFG\0957BC/**1081991**/BGR/
to
Customer Cube\BFG\0957BC//BGR/

and not change the second row column value
Customer Cube\BFG\0948271//BGF/INTEREST RATE PRODUCTS/

As the second one does not have any number after the first forward slash until the second forward slash.

I have a code that used to work and it does not any more so I have changed it and was expecting it to work but it does not.

Can you please point me to what I am doing wrong?

thanks
Baris

import re

....

results_2017=pd.read_csv(file_path)

results_2017.replace({'/[0-9]+/', '//'}, regex=True, inplace=True)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
results_2017.replace('/\d+/', '//', inplace=True, regex=True)
```

You passed first 2 arguments as a single **set**.

Another alternative is:

```
results_2017.replace({'/\d+/': '//'}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Pass *to_replace* as a **dictionary**.